# Eclipse Symfony 2 environments not found

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony, eclipse-pdt

I am experiencing a problem: Eclipse doesn't detect the environments of my Symfony 2 project.

This means I can't configure the "Launch Configuration". I have no idea why... I use the Plugin from here: http://symfony.dubture.com/

This is how it looks on my PC (empty dropdown menu for the environments): http://abload.de/image.php?img=eclipsesymfony2env0lu66.png

This is how it should look like: http://symfony.dubture.com/images/screenshots/configuration_tab.png

In the folder `app/config`, there are a `config.yml` and `config_dev.yml`, `config_prod.yml` and `config_test.yml` among some other files.

Versions:
Symfony 2.7
Eclipse 4.4.2 (PHP Plugin and the Symfony 2 plugin are up to date)
PHP 5.6 VC11 x86 Thread Safe
Apache 2.4.10 VC11 x86
Win 7 SP 1 x64 (admin account)

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that routing code assist works (for ex. source -> insert symfony route). If not, make sure "Dumped container" path is set correctly (project properties -> symfony)
2. Create launch profile and select web/app(_dev)?.php file
3. Go to symfony tab ;)

Comment: The "Dumped container" path points to `app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml` (this is the default setting). This file exists, but got several validation errors. All these errors start with "cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'factory'." I never modified this file.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find environments, plugin Symfony Dubture needs *web* folder added to Include Path (Project Properties -> PHP -> Include Path -> Source tab -> Add Folder button -> *web* folder should be checked).

Current version of the Symfony Feature (1.1.1) has all controls disabled in [Symfony tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqdPY.png) in launch configuration dialog. Code which obtained environments and routes stopped working correctly and hence this tab is now turned off and should not be used.

In order to run/debug Symfony app, launch configuration should be configured [manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9IKW.png). It can be done in the following steps:

- In Debug/Run Configuration dialog, create new PHP Web Application configuration.
- In File field enter text in the format: `\<projectName>\web\app_dev.php`.
- In the Server box, select Configure button to open Edit Server dialog.
- In the Server tab, Document Root field should point to the project parent folder.
- Prior to use of the created launch configuration, start the php built-in web server using the command: `php -S localhost -t path/to/project/parent/folder`